# Create X amount of empty arrays based on input

Tags: javascript, arrays

A user dynamically chooses a value X. Based on the value, X, I want to create unique empty arrays. How would I go about that?

For example, user chooses 4.

I want the following output:

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = []; 
var array3 = [];
var array4 = [];
```

Is there a way to properly doing this?

Comment: Why not an array of arrays? `var array = [ [], [], [], [] ];` - much easier to work with, surely?

Comment: Is an array of arrays acceptable?

Comment: Whenever you have multiple variables with names like `somethingX` where `X` is an increasing number, or you want to create variables dynamically, you instead want a **collection** of values. Having dynamic variables is almost always bad design.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the name of a property on an object using the square brackets with a string input:

```
var obj = {};
var numberOfArrays = 4;

for(var i = 1; i <= numberOfArrays; i++){
    obj['array' + i] = []; // Specify the name of the array property
}

console.log(obj); // Logs an object which has 4 empty arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement Steven`s answer, you could also create an array of arrays:

```
var numberOfArrays = X;
var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < numberOfArrays; i++){
    arr.push(new Array());
}
```

Comment: You would want to parameterize the 4